# Can I create a new element on a screen by coding blocks?

Tags: app-inventor

In MIT App Inventor, can I create a new element (eg. a new textbox, button, label) on a screen by coding blocks, instead of drag&drop it via the Designer?

Comment: no, you only can create components in the Designer, see also [these forum threads](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mitappinventortest/create$20components$20during$20runtime%7Csort:relevance)

Comment: Thank you, Taifun!